# Dúvida sobre listas encadeadas e remoção de nodos

Tags: c, lista, estrutura-de-dados, lista-encadeada, codeblocks

Tenho uma dúvida persistente na função remover_nodos que vou tentar apresentar de forma clara e coerente: por que o código 1 não funciona e entra em loop infinito mas o código 2 funciona? Quero saber se alguém conseguiu entender a lógica por trás e se pudesse me explicar como funciona agradeceria bastante. Abaixo seguem os códigos com a devida identificação de cada um.

**Código 1 da função remover_nodos que não funciona e entra em loop:**

```
struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        free(aux);
        aux = paux;
    }

    return cabeca;
};
```

**Código 2 da função remover_nodos que funciona:**

```
struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover - 1); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }
    return cabeca;
};
```

**Código geral do programa com o código 2 na função remover_nodos:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Nodo
{
    int informacao;
    struct Nodo *proximo;
};

struct Nodo *criar_lista(void)
{
    return NULL;
}

struct Nodo *insercao_nodos(int valor, struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *novo = (struct Nodo*)malloc(sizeof(struct Nodo));
    novo->informacao = valor;
    novo->proximo = cabeca;
    return novo;
};

void imprimir_valores(struct Nodo *cabeca)
{
    struct Nodo *aux;

    for(aux = cabeca; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo)
    {
        printf("%d\t", aux->informacao);
    }
}

struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux->proximo != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        aux->proximo = paux->proximo;
        free(paux);
    }
    return cabeca;
};

int main()
{
    struct Nodo *cabeca;
    int tam = 0;
    int qtd_remover = 0;
    cabeca = criar_lista();
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(4, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(1, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(3, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(2, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(5, cabeca);
    tam++;
    printf("VALORES INSERIDOS\n");
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);
    printf("\nREMOCAO DE NODOS\n");
    printf("Nodos inseridos: %d", tam);
    printf("\nNodos a remover: ");
    scanf("%d", &qtd_remover);
    while(qtd_remover > tam)
    {
        printf("Quantidade de nodos a remover e maior que a quantidade de nodos existentes! Digite novamente: ");
        scanf("%d", &qtd_remover);
    }
    cabeca = remover_nodos(cabeca, tam, qtd_remover);
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Considere a versão que não funciona**

```
struct Nodo *remover_nodos(struct Nodo *cabeca, int tamanho, int qtd_para_remover)
{
    struct Nodo *aux = cabeca, *paux;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < (tamanho - qtd_para_remover); i++)
    {
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }

    while(aux != NULL)
    {
        paux = aux->proximo;
        free(aux);
        aux = paux;
    }

    return cabeca;
};
```

E o seguinte contexto: Dois nodes, de endereços `A` e `B`. E a chamada de `remover_nodos()` para remover 1 node.

- o `for` vai posicionar `aux` em `B`
- ao entrar no while vai liberar o node `B` como esperado
- `aux` vai apontar então para `NULL` e o `while` termina

**Mas A->proximo continua apontando para `B` que não existe mais e o programa está condenado.**

### mais sobre `remover_nodos()` e a estrutura da lista

Acho que o modo como escreveu é frágil e complicado. Imagino que tenha um enunciado a seguir, mas

- entenda que essa função em geral não faz parte de uma implementação de lista: elementos em uma lista ligada são acessados 1 a 1. Funções que removem todos ou alguns nós não são comuns
- a noção de encapsulamento é importante e facilita muito as coisas: a lista tem metadatos, o tamanho, os endereços do primeiro e em geral do último registro devem ficar dentro da lista e as funções serem escritas em torno de listas apenas
- escreva em torno dos dados: seu programa implementa listas ligadas e nem tem essa estrutura
- muitas vezes a inserção pode ser no início ou no fim, com duas funções
- é muito mais complicado usar ponteiros para um lado só e não o contrário: navegar pela lista é muito chato quando só tem ponteiros para um lado. Simples é a lista que tem ponteiros para os dois lados, mesmo que a apostila diga o contrário.
- a lista ligada é uma estrutura que vincula nodes e não dados. Cada node é que contem ou aponta para um dado. Assim são 3 estruturas e seu programa só tem uma: o Node em si. Só vai ter mais trabalho programando assim. E vai ficar mais frágil e vai ter que passar mais parâmetros e manter mais controles no programa.
- aproveitar as funções em outras listas será mais difícil
- use nomes mais curtos para variáveis que vai usar a toda hora

### EXEMPLO

#### a lista em torno dos dados

Uma lista é uma coleção possivelmente vazia de nós. Cada nó tem um dado ou aponta para um dado.

```
typedef int DADO;
```

começando por isso pode mudar a definição para qualquer tipo de lista: uma letrinha, um `int`, aquela inevitável lista de livros, a playlist, a lista de alunos e todos aqueles programas de lista passam a ser quase o mesmo ;)

```
typedef struct Nodo_
{
    DADO*        info;
    struct Nodo_* prox;

}   Nodo;
```

Um nó da lista é isso: aponta para um dado, seja lá o que for o dado. Em geral é mais simples ter um ponteiro para cada lado, porque a navegação fica muito mais fácil. Claro, gasta um ponteiro a mais.

```
typedef struct 
{
    size_t tam;
    Node*  cabeca;

}   Lista;
```

E afinal a `Lista` é isso: não tem referência aos dados. Apenas aos nós. E contém o tamanho.

Veja um trecho de seu programa:

```
    struct Nodo* cabeca;
    int          tam         = 0;
    cabeca                   = criar_lista();
    cabeca                   = insercao_nodos(4, cabeca);
    tam++;
    cabeca = insercao_nodos(1, cabeca);
```

`tam` deveria estar dentro da lista. inserir um nó numa lista já deveria mudar o tamanho ou vai ter sempre que fazer fora da rotina que insere e isso não faz sentido: é um convite ao erro. O que se quer é inserir um dado numa lista. `criar_lista()` deveria retornar uma lista e não um `Node` mesmo porque a lista vai estar vazia. E o tamanho como 0 deveria estar DENTRO da lista e ser um valor SEM sinal.

```
    printf("VALORES INSERIDOS\n");
    imprimir_valores(cabeca);
```

Seria mais conveniente se `imprimir_valores()` já aceitasse um título. E um endereço de lista nunca o endereço de 1 nó: a lista pode estar vazia afinal.

#### juntando as sugestões em um exemplo

##### `main`

```
int main(void)
{
    Lista* lista = criar_lista();
    imprimir(lista, "\tlista criada!\n");
    for (int i = 20; i >= 1; i -= 1) inserir(i, lista);
    imprimir(lista, "inseridos [20..1]");
    remover(lista, 2);
    imprimir(lista, "removidos 2 elementos");
    remover(lista, lista->tam);
    imprimir(lista, "removido o resto da lista");
    lista = remover_lista(lista);
    imprimir(lista, "lista ja removida");
    return 0;
}
```

Esse exemplo:

- cria a lista
- tenta imprimir a lista ainda vazia
- insere 20 valores
- lista
- tenta apagar 2 valores e lista
- apaga todo o resto e lista
- remove a lista inteira e lista

E assim pode comparar duas maneiras de escrever isso.

veja por exemplo que `remover(lista, lista->tam-1)` removeria sempre todos exceto o primeiro elemento da lista e isso é mais simples de ler e entender

- não se trata o tamanho da lista em lugar nenhum
- `imprimir` aceita um título e isso facilita escrever os testes
- `remover_lista` retorna um ponteiro então permite invalidar o ponteiro da lista na mesma linha em que a lista é destruída

#### a saída do exemplo

```
        lista criada!

        Lista vazia!
inseridos [20..1]
        20 elementos:
   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
  11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
removidos 2 elementos
        18 elementos:
   1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
  11    12    13    14    15    16    17    18
removido o resto da lista
        Lista vazia!
```

#### o código do exemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef int DADO;

typedef struct Nodo_
{
    DADO          info;
    struct Nodo_* prox;

} Node;

typedef struct
{
    size_t tam;
    Node*  cabeca;

} Lista;

Lista* criar_lista(void);
int    imprimir(Lista*, const char*);
int    inserir(DADO valor, Lista*);
int    remover(Lista*, size_t);
Lista* remover_lista(Lista*);

int main(void)
{
    Lista* lista = criar_lista();
    imprimir(lista, "\tlista criada!\n");
    for (int i = 20; i >= 1; i -= 1) inserir(i, lista);
    imprimir(lista, "inseridos [20..1]");
    remover(lista, 2);
    imprimir(lista, "removidos 2 elementos");
    remover(lista, lista->tam);
    imprimir(lista, "removido o resto da lista");
    lista = remover_lista(lista);
    imprimir(lista, "lista ja removida");
    return 0;
}

Lista* criar_lista(void)
{
    Lista* nv = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    if (nv == NULL) return NULL;
    nv->tam    = 0;
    nv->cabeca = NULL;
    return nv;
}

int imprimir(Lista* lst, const char* tit)
{
    if (lst == NULL) return -1;
    if (tit != NULL) printf("%s\n", tit);
    if (lst->tam == 0)
        printf("\tLista vazia!\n");
    else
        printf("\t%d elementos:\n", lst->tam);
    const size_t nc = 10;  // 16 bytes per line
    size_t       j  = 1;
    Node*        um = lst->cabeca;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lst->tam; i += 1)
    {
        printf("%4d  ", um->info);
        um = um->prox;
        if (j >= nc)
            printf("\n"), j = 1;
        else
            j += 1;
    }
    if (j != 1) printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

int inserir(DADO valor, Lista* lst)
{
    if (lst == NULL) return -1;
    Node* novo = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    novo->info = valor;
    novo->prox = lst->cabeca;
    lst->tam += 1;
    lst->cabeca = novo;
    return 0;
};

int remover(Lista* lst, size_t qtd)
{  // remove qtd itens do final da lista
    if (lst == NULL) return -1;  // sem lista
    if (qtd > lst->tam) return -2;
    if (qtd == 0) return 0;
    // adianta (tam-qtd) itens
    Node* p = lst->cabeca;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lst->tam - qtd;
         i += 1, p = p->prox)
        ;
    // apaga os qtd nodes
    for (size_t i = 0; i < qtd; i += 1)
    {
        Node* temp = p->prox;
        free(p);
        p = temp;
        lst->tam -= 1;  // 1 a menos
    }
    return 0;
}

Lista* remover_lista(Lista* l)
{
    if (l == NULL) return NULL;
    Node* p = l->cabeca;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l->tam; i += 1)
    {  // apaga um por um
        Node* temp = p->prox;
        free(p);
        p = temp;
    };
    free(l);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ah os vigilantes do SO! Então uma resposta que vai direto ao assunto, comenta o problema, apresenta um exemplo com código completo e comentado, e mais o resultado é determinada como inútil. E sobre aquela recomendação do próprio SO sobre apresentar relevantes sugestões para que pessoas menos preparadas (eu, nesse caso) possam melhorar suas respostas? Nada como o anonimato.